# Где как размещать mp3 файлы для приложения

Tags: android, файловая-система

Есть необходимость загрузить на телефон несколько mp3 файлов. Данные файлы должно использовать приложение.
Первоначально пытался добавить файл mp3 в assert получил [такую проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613751/how-to-register-new-file-type-association-with-mp3)
Побыстрому побороть не смог.
Да и файлы необходимо загружать уже посте установки приложения.
Необходима загрузка файлов во внутреннюю память телефона.

Подскажите как быть. Попытался создать произвольный файл

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_APPEND)));            
bw.write("Содержимое файла");            
bw.close();
```

Файл создается, но в через ES Проводник его на устройстве найти не могу.

Comment: mp3 файлы в `res/raw/` ложат

Comment: @pavlofff `res/raw/` да, так и сделал для предустановленного файла. Поправьте если ошибаюсь, насколько понимаю `res/raw/` используется как раз для предустановленных файлов (файлов являющихся неотъемлемой частью приложения). а у меня потребность дать возможность пользователю самому загрузить необходимые файлы, которые будет использовать приложение

Comment: Да, верно, каталог */res/raw/* только для статических данных, их можно только читать, но нельзя изменять или дописывать туда. Как и все другие каталоги внутри проекта (а в итоге .apk), впрочем.

Comment: @pavlofff а как быть с внешними файлами, подскажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот так можно обращаться с файлами приложения (файлы, которые создает приложение или загружает их) читать и создавать их.

```
String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
```

Далее этот файл можно открыть и для Input и для Output.

Comment: или я что-то недопонимаю (просветите) или не так формулирую вопрос. Имена файлов и их кол-во будет известно только после установки приложения. Каталог расположения файлов предполагается или условно произвольный (созданный пользователем) или какой-то заранее созданный приложением.

Comment: Мой вариант предлагает возможность работать с файлами, которые были созданы во внутреннем хранилище приложения. Т.е. когда вы устанавливаете приложение, оно создает папку, в которой может хранить все свои созданные или скаченные файлы.

Comment: да, я это понял. но у меня несколько другая проблема. не складывается картинка, как создать приложением каталог, в который пользователь будет помещать файлы. (либо пользователь сам создаст каталог и укажет его приложению).

Comment: я даже банально не могу найти файл, который создается приложением по имени (ES Проводником в режиме root и отображая скрытые файлы, через поиск пытался найти)

Comment: File file = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            stream.write(data);
            stream.close();

Comment: так создаем файл в приложении, а чтобы прочитать созданные читаем вот так : String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
            int length = (int) file.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
            stream.read(bytes);

Comment: А если вам нужно именно уметь создавать свои папки и читать потом из них, то вот так можно делать их : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794974/create-folder-in-android

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно! каталог создался именно в памяти телефона. Много раз видел примеры с WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE но я их воспринимал как работа с внешней картой памяти, а необходим был каталог во внутренней памяти. (хотя на телефоне и внутренняя память и SD карта обозначены как sdcard и sdcard2 соответственно.

Comment: Рад, что помогло) Можете отметить мой ответ, как правильный) Буду благодарен)